# Installing Rouge on Windows

Tags: perl

After successfully installing XML::DOM Perl module when I try to install DB_File Perl module I

get the following error message. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem and install Rouge on

my Windows machine?

```
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Parsing config.in...
Looks Good.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -ldb
Writing Makefile for DB_File
cp DB_File.pm blib\lib\DB_File.pm
AutoSplitting blib\lib\DB_File.pm (blib\lib\auto\DB_File)
C:/Perl/site/bin/gcc.exe -c  -I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB/include    -DNDEBUG -DWIN32 -D_CONSOLE 

-DNO_STRICT -DHAVE_DES_FCRYPT -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -DPRIVLIB_LAST_IN_INC -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT 

-DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -DPERL_MSVCRT_READF IX -DHASATTRIBUTE -fno-strict-aliasing 

mms-bitfields -O2 -DVERSION=\"1. 824\"   -DXS_VERSION=\"1.824\"  "-IC:\Perl\lib\CORE"  

-D_NOT_CORE  -DmDB_Prefix_t=size_t -DmDB_Hash_t=u_int32_t version.c version.c:30:16: db.h: 
No such file or directory 
dmake.exe:  Error code 129, while making 'version.o' PMQS/DB_File-1.824.tar.gz
C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
PMQS/DB_File-1.824.tar.gz                    : make NO
```

Comment: It appears the package requires BerkeleyDB to be installed.  [Try following the instructions here](http://mathieu.carbou.free.fr/wiki/index.php?title=Berkeley_DB_for_MinGW) and then attempt to install DB_File again.

Answer (score 4):

The important part is:

> db.h: No such file or directory

The compiler wants to link against `libdb` ([BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/downloads/)). Install it.

Answer (score 0):

What Perl version are you using on your Windows box? It looks like [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) because I can see references to *mingw*. However, the line that's killing you is:

```
-D_NOT_CORE  -DmDB_Prefix_t=size_t -DmDB_Hash_t=u_int32_t version.c version.c:30:16: db.h:  No such file or directory
```

I am assuming that you don't have the `db.h` header file.

How did you install the DB_File Perl module? Are you using the `cpan` command? Or, did you download it manually? If you use the `cpan` command, it'll make sure that all prerequisites are installed.

You can also try [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl) which comes with the Perl_DB module already installed. Plus, you might find the ActivePerl Perl Package Manager easier to use. ActiveState packages many of the most popular Perl modules which means you don't need the complete developer environment in order to install them.

Let us know:

- Which PC version of Perl you're using
- Your OS (Windows XP? Windows Vista?)
- How you are trying to install these modules

And, I can probably give you more specific help.