# Problems with ROUGE on Windows

Tags: perl

I am trying to use ROUGE on Windows:

So the first few lines of the file:

```
use XML::DOM;
use DB_File;
use Getopt::Std;
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
use vars qw($opt_a $opt_b $opt_c $opt_d $opt_e $opt_f $opt_h $opt_H $opt_m $opt_n $opt_p $opt_s $opt_t $opt_l $opt_v $opt_w $opt_2 $opt_u $opt_x $opt_U $opt_3 $opt_M $opt_z);
```

And it gives me this error:

```
    Can't locate DB_File.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib
 .) at C:\RELEASE-1.5.5\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl line 174.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\RELEASE-1.5.5\ROUGE-1.5.5.pl line 174.
```

I am new to perl. All i need is ROUGE to work. What does this mean? How can i fix it?

Comment: DB_File needs to be installed. Note that installing DB_File requires Berkeley DB to be installed on your machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Rouge on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178561/installing-rouge-on-windows)

Comment: Berkley DB is not installing right. I'll try fixing

Answer (score 2):

The author of the perl script probably did not test his script
on windows.
You could probably hack the script to make it work, but
since you're new to perl and seem to be in a hurry,
I suggest you use linux/unix for ROGUE.
The README for ROGUE mentions linuxy things like bash etc,
which is a clue.

If you insist, here's a way to get the perl script running
on windows, but be warned, further errors can pop up
as you get deeper in to the features.

remove activeperl

install strawberryperl 32bit

```
cpan install XML:DOM
cpan install DB_File
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

close existing windows

open a new command prompt
run this command

```
ppm install DB_File
```

close window
try running rogue again
hope it helps
---
if you have a copy of the rogue application please share it so we can check it out.

Comment: I tried your command. It says 'No missing package to install'. But ROUGE still doesn't work.

Comment: Just download Berkley DB. How can i use it for installing DB_File.ppm